# WooCommerce: Get reviews from products in array and sort them by stars

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, comments, product

I want to show some reviews based on a list of products.
The product IDs are stored in an array. So I tried the following:

```
<?php
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'number'  => '5',
    'post_id' => array('2360','2362'),
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments);
?>
```

It looks, that `post_id` does not allow an array of IDs.
If I try it with only one ID it works fine.

EDIT: I found a way to order by star rating:

```
'meta_key' => 'rating',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to show to show some reviews based on a specific products, you need to use `post__in` argument instead of `post_id` like:

```
<?php
$comments = get_comments( array (
    'number'    => '5',
    'post__in'  => array('2360','2362'), // <= HERE your array of product Ids
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key'  => 'rating',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'     => 'DESC'
) );

wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ), $comments);
?>
```

It should works now. See [`WP_Comment_Query` available parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that these arguments are also available. Works fine.